# Flex custom skin does not bring up IOS Softkeyboard

Tags: ios, apache-flex, textinput

When I create a custom skin for the TextInput on Flex 4.6, this textInput does not call the iOS Softkeyboard on activation.

Is there anything I can do to change this?

Comment: Could you perhaps post the relevant source code? That would make the diagnosis much easier.

Comment: Not really, just a default Skin based on the TextInput component is al there is to it...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using standard TextInput skin class for desktop applications as base class for your custom skin, but for mobile applications you should use mobile skin: spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin